# Generating a decision tree using J48 algorithm

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree, c4.5

I want to create a GUI using NetBeans and using the WEKA library. One button to upload an arff file that contains the data and another to generate a decision tree using J48 algorithm. All the tutorials online shows how to generate using the WEKA explorer but how can I do this in our GUI?

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to build a classifier programatically without the weka explorer?

This will build your classifier:

```
Reader r = new FileReader("/path/to/file.arff");

Instances i = new Instances(r);

Classifier c = new J48();
c.buildClassifier(i);
```

The necessary imports are:

```
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.Instances;
```

The only thing your GUI has to do is to provide the path to the ARFF file.

I hope this will answer your question.